# I have list of nested dict variable and need to convert to dict variable type for Json object

Tags: python, json, boto3

Below json data has 3 rules (dict type). I have created as list with some changes. Now i need to convert this "list to dict" data type. The below data has lot of nested list/dict.  I want to split this list of list (3 list) and append it to dictionary.(dict datatype)

`<class 'list'>`

```
[
{'ID': 'Glacierize bird_sporr after 2 weeks', 
 'Status': 'Enabled', 
 'Transitions': [{'Days': 14, 'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'}], 
 'NoncurrentVersionTransitions': [{'NoncurrentDays': 14, 'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'}], 
  'Prefix': 'bird_sporr'}, 
{'Expiration': 
    {'Days': 45}, 
    'ID': 'Delete files after 45 days', 
     'Status': 'Enabled', 
     'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {'NoncurrentDays': 45}, 
     'Prefix': 'bird_sporr'
 }, 
 {'ID': 'PruneAbandonedMultipartUpload', 
  'Status': 'Enabled',
   'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {'DaysAfterInitiation': 30},
   'Prefix': ''}
]
```

I need the below output with dict data type.. This API will not acccept the list data type. Please help on this.  Let me know if any queries.

`<class 'dict'>`

```
{'ID': 'Glacierize bird_sporr after 2 weeks', 
'Status': 'Enabled', 
'Transitions': [{'Days': 14, 'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'}], 
 'NoncurrentVersionTransitions': [{'NoncurrentDays': 14, 'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'}], 
 'Prefix': 'bird_sporr'}, 
{'Expiration': 
    {'Days': 45}, 
    'ID': 'Delete files after 45 days', 
    'Status': 'Enabled', 
    'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {'NoncurrentDays': 45}, 
    'Prefix': 'bird_sporr'},
 {'ID': 'PruneAbandonedMultipartUpload', 
  'Status': 'Enabled',
  'AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload': {'DaysAfterInitiation': 30}, 
  'Prefix': ''}
```

Comment: If the first item is what you have and the sencond item what you expect then select the first element (element 0 of your list) it will be the dictionary you are looking for. Example: `list_of_dicts = [ {..} ] `

then `first_dict = list_of_dicts[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just that, you have a list with your output. But you need just the output, without it being contained by a list, Then you should simply be able to do this:

list[0] should give you your desired dictionary.